# npm install on Windows takes forever

Tags: windows, npm

I am trying

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

on Windows 10 and it seems to take forever. Anyone else has had a similar issue? I am using the node version 6.10 and the npm version is 3.10.

Comment: is there any output? does it freeze or is simply taking a long time?

Comment: It is just stuck at a line 
"[    ..............] - fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js"

Comment: Am sorry for the abruptly ending comment. Well the npm install is just stuck at that line for hours together. 
Btw, I am using node version 6.10.3 and npm version 3.10.10 on a Windows 10 machine on home network. 
I have tried both the Node Windows Binary Package (.zip) and the Node Windows Installer (.msi). It is showing the same result. Not sure what is the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Also broken for me on linux ubuntu 16 - my problem was that i installed npm package standalone - instead i had to install the latest nodejs and use the npm provided with that. then everything runs as normal

Comment: is it getting stuck for you as well at a similar line?